# Передать несколько фото на сервер Android

Tags: java, android

В приложении использую rxjava2 retrofit 2.
Нужно передать фотографии сделаные в приложении на сервер(6 фото) в разные папки так что сделать одним запросом не получится. я пытаю делать List  с фотками и запускать POST запросы в цикле for но у меня вылетает ошибка.
Каким способом можно реализовать это?

Comment: было бы немного легче вам помочь, если бы вы показали вашу ошибку.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko ошибка в том что в цикле нельзя вызывать метод апи.
Я не прошу исправить ошибку, я спрашиваю  совет как выгрузить 6 фото на сервер правильно

Comment: Очень странно, что в ошибке написано что в цикле нельзя вызвать метод апи. Не верю! Что это за метод такой, который нельзя вызвать в цикле? Думаю, что вы что-то не так поняли. Покажите текст ошибки.

Comment: @JunDev вставьте пожалуйста сюда вашу ошибку. Думаю что проблема очень простая

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.
        at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:111)